# Calling ActionResult using jquery ajax in .net core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

Action in controller

Method GetById is the same as the Find method and EntityUpdate == Update

```
public IActionResult CategoryStatus(int id)
    {
        var data = cm.GetById(id);
        if (data.CategoryStatus)
        {
            data.CategoryStatus = false;
        }
        else
        {
            data.CategoryStatus = true;
        }
        cm.EntityUpdate(data);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I want to call this action from razor view with ajax, can anyone help , thanks.

I add some parts of razor view just in case

```
 <a href="/Admin/Category/CategoryStatus/@item.CategoryID"
    class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm"
    onclick="return functionConfirm(this)">
    Aktivləşdir
 </a>
<script>
function functionConfirm(event) {
          swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You will not be able to recover this item!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: 'No',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success'
    }, function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            $.ajax({//I need your help here
                type: "GET",
                 url: '/Admin/Category/CategoryStatus',
                success: function (msg) {
                    console.log(msg);
                 },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    console.log(msg);
                }
            });
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like below:

```
    //add this....
<a data-id="@item.CategoryID"
    class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm"
    onclick="return functionConfirm()">
    Aktivləşdir
 </a>       
@section Scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" integrity="sha512-gOQQLjHRpD3/SEOtalVq50iDn4opLVup2TF8c4QPI3/NmUPNZOk2FG0ihi8oCU/qYEsw4P6nuEZT2lAG0UNYaw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js" integrity="sha512-7VTiy9AhpazBeKQAlhaLRUk+kAMAb8oczljuyJHPsVPWox/QIXDFOnT9DUk1UC8EbnHKRdQowT7sOBe7LAjajQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>   
    <script>
        function functionConfirm() {
            swal({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You will not be able to recover this item!",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                cancelButtonText: 'No',
                cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
                showConfirmButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success'
                }, function (isConfirm) {
                    var id = $(event).data("id"); //add....
                    if (!isConfirm) return;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '/Admin/Category/CategoryStatus/'+id, //modify...
                        success: function (msg) {
                            window.location.href="/xxx/Index"
                            },
                        error: function (req, status, error) {
                            console.log(msg);
                        }
                    });
            });
        }

</script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but It doesn't work , I need id parametr on the CategoryStatus method

Comment: Hi @Ilkin Rufullayev, updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for helping It works after a while :)